# Question regarding the distance time diagrams

Tags: kinematics

this is very easy question rather it can be silly question for you, but this question is from my text book.

See this example.

There is a partical in the point A, and it moves to B with a constant velocity. There is 2m distance from A to B. There is a person at B who wants to find the speed of the paricle. So, his electric watch shows partical spends 2 seconds for this movement.

Draw the distance-time diagram for the particle according to the man.

Find the speed using the diagram.

The answer in the book is this.

[image]

My problen is how the distance has decreased with the time. According to my knowledge the distance can't decrease ever with the time.

For this problem my teacher  says it is due to the sentence of 'according to the person'(see the first question). But then I arise another quesion

The m (tan theta) of the diagram shows the speed of the partical according to the man. But then the tan theta shows a minus value. So, how the speed is a minus value. ( If this was a displacenent -time diagram we can determine only the magnitude and drop the minus sign. But this is a distance-time diagram.).

Where is the problem.....In my thinking or the test book.... please explain me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example a person is observing a particle.

The position of the particle from the person is $\vec x$ and this is equal to $x\,\hat x$ where $x$ is the distance of the particle relative to the person in the positive $x$ direction.

In terms of a series of diagrams this is what the motion of the particle looks like.

[image]

The red arrow shows the displacement (vector) of the particle relative to the person.

As time progresses you will note that the length of the red arrow decreases as the particle is moving in the negative $x$ direction.

Eventually the particle reaches the same position as the person.

So the particle started at position $2.5\,\hat x$ relative to the person and after $2.5\, \rm s$ reaches the person so its new position is $0\, \hat x$

The change in the position is $\vec x_{\rm final} - \vec x_{\rm initial } = 0 \,\hat x - 2.5 \, \hat x = - 2.5 \, \hat x$ meaning that the particle has moved a distance of $2.5 \,\rm m$ in the negative $x$ direction.

So the velocity of the particle is $\dfrac {\text{change in position}}{\text{time taken}} = \dfrac{-2.5\, \hat x}{2.5} = -1 \,\hat x \,\rm m\,s^{-1}$

So the particle is changing its position relative to the person by one metre every second (the particles speed) whilst moving in the negative $x$ direction.

So you can think of the velocity as $1\, (-\hat x) \,\rm m\,s^{-1}$ where $-\hat x$ is the negative $x$ direction.

---

The vertical axis on your graph is the component of the position of the particle in the positive $x$ direction.

Answer (score 2):

> According to my knowledge the distance can't decrease ever with the time.

Distance is "how far away is it". That depends on your point of view. For A, the distance is increasing as the particle is moving away; for B, the distance is decreasing as the particle is moving towards him.

The particle starts out 2 m away from B, and ends up right next to him. That means that the distance is initially 2 m, and ends up being just 0 m.

That gives us two points on the graph: the point (0 sec, 2 m), and a second point (2 sec, 0 m). If the particle is moving at a constant velocity, the line connecting those points will be straight.

As you say, the slope of the line is negative. That means that the velocity is negative, according to B. Again - if we say that "positive change in distance with time = positive velocity", then it follows that "negative change in distance with time = negative velocity".

Velocity is a vector: it has magnitude and direction. In this case, we can express the answer in a few different ways: I would prefer to say "the speed is 1 m/s towards B", as that is very explicit about both the magnitude and the direction (without having to worry about whether B is to the left or the right of A, for example).

Comment: Sir,as you saying  "the speed is 1 m/s towards B" then haven't you considered the direction due to the word 'towards' . Then isn't it become velocitity. The graphs m shows the speed...

Comment: *As you say, the slope of the line is negative. That means that the velocity is negative* sir is it velocity is negative or speed is negative

Comment: @OsalSelaka Speed is never negative, because it does not have a direction. The velocity is negative because for B when distance away from him increases this is the +ve direction. The motion is towards B so the velocity relative to B is -ve. The gradient of your graph indicates speed. Whether the slope is up or down indicates the direction of velocity  (up = away from B = distance from B increasing, down = towards B = distance from B decreasing).